# How to retrieve metadata from a feature layer in ArcGIS Server 10 using Flex

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-api

I need to retrieve the metadata information from a feature layer. I have the web services available and I can run queries to retrieve the feature attributes, but I don't know any method to retrieve the metadata. Is there any sample or code snippet that I can use to understand the method?

Comment: By meta data, do you mean the actual metadata of the featureclasses? Or do you want all that information that one sees on the mapservice page?

Comment: I mean the actual metadata. I think I can get the Map Service information via a JSON request (am I right?!), but I don't know if the actual metadata could be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arcgis Server directly cannot serve the metadata for your geographic data.

I believe that ESRI's Geoportal can do so: http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/geoportal

Answer (score 2):

I believe that as of ArcGIS Server 10.1 access to metadata for map services is now supported through the REST services:

> ...The metadata is also available to web developers using a REST
>   request. Developers can append /info/metadata to the end of a
>   service's REST URL to get an XML file containing all the service's
>   metadata. Developers can parse this metadata and present it to the end
>   user of the service in the desired format....

Source and more info here:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//015400000579000000

Note that I'm not sure if this applies to metadata for individual layers within a map service, or just the entire service as a whole....